# Neo4j: Cypher signalling existence when matching nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a cypher query like:

```
MATCH (user:USER)
WHERE user.userName = {userName}
RETURN user
```

I return the whole user object if a user exists with a matching username. If all I care about is if the user exists or not is there a way to return something that signals existence of a matching node? (this will cut down on data transfer if nothing else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this do what you want?

```
MATCH (user:User {userName:{userName}})
RETURN 1 = count (user) as exists
```

or, if "exist" includes cases with more than one matching node

```
RETURN 0 < count (user) as exists
```

or just

```
RETURN count (user) as cnt
```